# Build SDK to get Openwrt image

Tags: openwrt

I tried to build an SDK file to get OpenWRT image but the output directory is 5GB. So what's right build to get OpenWRT image? (SKW71-Atheros_AR9331)

Answer (score 0):

1. first install

sudo apt-get install subversion build-essential libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev gawk git ccache gettext libssl-dev xsltproc wget

2.download openwrt 15.05 
git clone -b chaos_calmer git://github.com/openwrt/openwrt.git

3. cd openwrt
4. ./scripts/feeds update -a
   ./scripts/feeds install -a
5. make menuconfig
6. then select for which router or chip u want
   use arrow key to up or down ,use space bar to select any option,
   for select exit save configuration yes

7.command to build image use any one then
 make V=s or make V=99 or make -j1 V=s

8. wait for 4 to 5 hrs depends on your internet speed

Comment: or else if u dont want to make image from ur own then u can download from openwrt          https://downloads.openwrt.org/

Answer (score 0):

Openwrt build in default configuration includes so many different components, i.e

- cross-compiler
- supporting tools required to build cross-compiler
- kernel, and
- lots of packages

And everything is build from it's source code.
So, when you clone the repo it's size is minimal, but based upon your configuration it will download the rest of the things and compile them.

### On the other hand, Openwrt image of very smaller size and gets generated based on the user configuration in openwrt/bin/< target> directory.

So, if you only require the binary then you can download it from https://downloads.openwrt.org/, but if you want to customize the binary or add/remove any package then you need the source code.